Multimeter short circuit
I am a beginner in electronics, and I recently bought the Arduino student kit from the official Arduino website. I followed the course until the lesson with the multimeter. I built a simple circuit: + from pin 13 of Arduino uno to breadboard with a resistor and a led, to - and ground in the uno board. I measured the voltage according to the tutorial. However, having no prior hands-on experience with electronics, I attempted to measure current and resistance the same way. Shortly after I realised that's not how you do it. I suppose I created a short circuit. Have I managed to fry something? The arduino board seems to be working fine, it didn't even disconnect from my laptop. Is the multimeter still safe to use?
The multimeter is XL830L. My laptop is working, as far as I can tell the arduino board is fine as well.

Can you edit your question and add that you were using a "xl830l" multimeter. Also, can you make it clear what is working and what is not working. It sounds like the laptop and Arduino is working. But the multi meter may no longer be working?

Yes the laptop and the arduino board is working, if the multimeter still measures current, does that indicate the fuse didn't blow? Also do you think it's worth it to purchase a USB hub to protect the laptop from accidental short circuits? Does it work that way?

I attempted to measure current and resistance the same way Can you clarify what "the same way" was? Exactly where did you connect the multimeter pins? Across pin 13 and ground? Across the LED? Across the resistor? In series with the resistor?

Yes across the pin 13 and ground but the probes were touching the wire connected to the breadboard. The red probe touching end of the wire that was in the + column and the black one the end of the wire that was in the - column. Not the wires that connected the breadboard and the +/- columns to pin 13/ground, if that makes any difference. The voltage was measured properly in parallel and basically I tried measuring current and resitance with the same layout.

Just to be clear, voltage in measured in parallel to a device you want to check up on. Like an LED. Current is measured in series. Again w/the LED, you would have to break the circuit open an insert the current meter to complete the circuit.  Doesn't matter which side of the LED. So, going on, you tried to measure the current from the positive to negative power wires.  Likely you put 500mA across your multi meter. And from the pictures of a XL830L, we see clearly that exceeds the mA limit printed next to the low current / voltage port. So, the low current part of your meter may be broken.

So if the multimeter still measures low current, does it mean the number is inaccurate or that the fuse just didn't blow and it still can be used?

Most multi meters are designed to measure high currents (in the Amp range) and low currents (in the Milliamp range (1/1000 of an Amp)). When measuring low current the red probe is normally connected to the same multi meter port as when measuring voltage. When measuring high current the red probe is normally moved to a special high current port.
Since you didn't mention moving the red probe, it is assumed you had left it in the low current / voltage measuring port.
Assuming the above is correct, it is likely the low current fuse inside the multi meter has blown doing its job (protecting the Arduino) and now needs replacement.
Multi meters vary greatly. This tutorial about replacing multi meter fuses might provide some general guidance.

Well yeah I had looked inside the multimeter before posting this, and there was no fuse, I guess the multimeter from the student kit is cheap. So do you think something was damaged the arduino board/multimeter or even my laptop?

Your laptop should moderate the current of a USB 2.0 port not to exceed 500mA. After that, the voltage should start dropping to protect the laptop. The Arduino outputs should be able to handle a couple dozen mA. I don't know when the multi meter low current protection on your meter will blow. An inexpensive meter might use a low value resistor as a fuse. Also, such a meter may solder fuses directly to the PCB to save money. Search for leaded fuses to see images of what they look like.

It's the xl830l multimeter. I'm quite sure the multimeter was showing like ~70-80 mA while the short circuit happened. That doesn't seem too high to me, considering short circuit means theoretically ~0 resistance, infinite current. Does this signify that the breadboard have some small intrinsic resistance?

A digital multi meter samples voltage (and current) at desecrate intervals and normally averages over that sample. Who knows what the instantaneous maximum current flow might have been. Most multi meters state a range of current it can measure right on the low current and high current multi meter ports. Exceeding the upper limit of the low current port will likely cause the fuse (or resistor) to fail. There is no such thing as zero resistance or infinite current in real life. Besides, your computer's USB 2.0 port should have limited the total current to 500mA just to protect its self.

Thanks for your help! It's much appreciated :)

@wolfgangmozart12  That doesn't seem too high to me, considering short circuit means theoretically ~0 resistance, infinite current. Yes, but the multimeter measures current by measuring the voltage drop over a small resistance, so it would not actually be zero resistance, and therefore not infinite current.
